# chaostoolkit rollbacks not happening unless --rollback-strategy explicitly specified

Tags: chaos

I am using chaostoolkit tool and earlier the rollbacks used to happen if the hypothesis fails after the method injects failure. Now I see a different behaviour and the rollbacks happen only if i specify --rollback-strategy = deviated or always. I have raised a github issue as well which has sample console outputs(https://github.com/chaostoolkit/chaostoolkit/issues/258).

Does anyone know what could be the reason? or some parm to set the rollback strategy in the experiment itself instead of specifying at CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this discussion happened. Just wanted to share my thinking on this.

Some time ago, I did a rather large refactoring internally and, as part of this, I believe I may have introduced this change without realising it.

I realised this some months ago but I'm not sure what path to take. My feeling is that I should revert back to the original, and specified behavior. But I'm concerned about the effect on existing deployments.